# How do I post a GET Request to Microsoft Graph Api?

Tags: php, microsoft-graph-api

I have an access token, but I need to send it to verify myself via the graph API. How do I make a get request there ?
The API is :

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/
```

I tried :

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me?access_token=
```

and

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/access_token=
```

But neither works, it says it's empty.

Thanks in advance

Comment: That should be explained in the documentation for that API. Where is it …?

Answer (score 2):

You need to add an Authorization header to the request containing the word Bearer and the authorization token:

```
Authorization: Bearer <access_token>
```

The token itself is a base64 encoded string.

This sample PHP application may help, [Microsoft Graph OneNote API PHP Sample](https://github.com/OneNoteDev/MsGraph_OneNoteApiSamplePHP). Of particular interest here would be lines `280`-`303` of [`submit.php`](https://github.com/OneNoteDev/MsGraph_OneNoteApiSamplePHP/blob/master/OneNoteSamplePHP/submit.php):

```php
function initCurl($type = 'multipart')
{
    $cookieValues = parseQueryString(@$_COOKIE['graph_auth']);
    //Since cookies are user-supplied content, it must be encoded to avoid header injection
    $encodedAccessToken = rawurlencode(@$cookieValues['access_token']);
    $initUrl = $this->getPagesEndpointUrlWithSectionName();
    $ch = curl_init($initUrl);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
    if ($type == 'multipart') {
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,array(
            "Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=$this->boundary\r\n".
            "Authorization: Bearer ".$encodedAccessToken
        ));
    }
    else { //simple single-part request
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,array(
            "Content-Type:text/html\r\n".
            "Authorization: Bearer ".$encodedAccessToken
        ));
    }
    //configures curl_exec() to return the response as a string rather than echoing it
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
    //use HTTP POST method
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST,true);
    return $ch;
}
```